# Dynamically created class rows not iterating through jQuery .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a several tables like this:

```
<table id="order-table">
    <tr class="row-header">                     
        <td class="row-checkbox-delete-all"><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash center"></div><input tabindex="-1" id="checkbox-delete-all" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="row-line"><spring:message code="createOrder.label.lineNumber.text"/></td>
        <td class="row-product-id"><spring:message code="createOrder.label.original.text"/></td>
        <td class="row-qty"><spring:message code="createOrder.label.quantity.text"/></td>
        <td class="row-description"><spring:message code="createOrder.label.description.text"/></td>
        <td class="row-abc6"><spring:message code="createOrder.label.abc6.text"/></td>
        <td class="row-abc8"><spring:message code="createOrder.label.abc8.text"/></td>
        <td class="row-upc"><spring:message code="createOrder.label.upc.text"/></td>
        <td class="row-ndc"><spring:message code="createOrder.label.ndc.text"/></td>                            
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="row-checkbox-delete-row"><input tabindex="-1" class="checkbox-delete-row" type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="row-target">10</td>
        <td class="row-product-id"><input class="id-target row-product-id" name="lineItem[0].originalInput" type="text" /></td>
        <td class="row-qty"><input class="qty-target row-qty" name="lineItem[0].quantity" type="text" value="1" /></td>
        <td class="row-description"></td>
        <td class="row-abc6"></td>
        <td class="row-abc8"><input readonly tabindex="-1" class="abc8-target row-abc8" name="lineItem[0].abc8" type="text" /></td>
        <td class="row-upc"></td>
        <td class="row-ndc"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="buttons-table-left">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="button-delete-items" type="button" title="<spring:message code="createOrder.btn.deleteItems.title"/>" /></td>
        <td><input id="button-cancel-order" type="button" title="<spring:message code="createOrder.btn.cancel.title"/>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="buttons-table-right">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="button-submit-order" type="submit" title="<spring:message code="createOrder.btn.submit.title"/>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Another function is generating dynamic lines which are added to the table based on the data returned from an AJAX call.  They have the same structure and class names as the first static row.

And some jQuery/JavaScript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Event Listeners Section

    $(document).on("click", "#button-delete-items", ajaxDeleteLine);
    $(document).on("focusout", ".id-target", ajaxGetData);

    function ajaxDeleteLine() {

        var i = 0;

        $(".checkbox-delete-row:checked").each(function() {
            i++;
            console.log(i);
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: contextPath + "/deletesLineItem.do",
            data: {
                lineIds: 1
            }
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            alert("Error: Failed to delete lines!");
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            //alert(data);
        });
    }
});
```

When I click `#button-delete-items` it's ***only iterating the first element in the log, not the dynamically created ones***. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $(".checkbox-delete-row:checked") refers to the input itself. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You might need a fiddle of this to help us figure it out.  Are the checkboxes checked?

Comment: @mitch: they are checked when I run my tests

Comment: This is how I debug something like this.  Grab your selector $(".checkbox-delete-row:checked") and run it in Firebug or Chrome's developer console.  See if the count matches the checked ones you see.

Comment: I did that... this is the result: >>> $(".checkbox-delete-row:checked");
Object[input.checkbox-delete-row property value = "on" attribute value = "null", input.checkbox-delete-row property value = "on" attribute value = "null", input.checkbox-delete-row property value = "on" attribute value = "null", input.checkbox-delete-row property value = "on" attribute value = "null"]

Comment: Hmmm, you should be iterating through those.  Just curious. can you ad the `var` keyword in front of the `i`.  Maybe your code is in strict mode.

Comment: I did add `var` but either way it should work. In JS a variable without `var` has global scope but is still valid.

Comment: @mitch: what do you mean iterating through "those?"  What exactly is "those" in this case?

Comment: Not in strict mode.  It will be seen as undefined. i think you need a jsfiddle put up somewhere for all of us to look at.

Comment: `$(.checkbox-delete-row:checked).each(function(){console.log($(this))});`

Comment: @dcodesmith: try that and getting a context error... also tried it in the live code and retested... nothing is making it to the log.

Comment: @Phillip 'those' is the array of elements returned from your selector.

Comment: @mitch: isn't that exactly what each is supposed to be doing?  PS I changed the selector to $(".input.checkbox-delete-row:checked") just in case. Didn't make a difference. Still nothing is being iterated.

Comment: @Phillip Yes.  If your selector worked then the $.each() should have worked. $(".input.checkbox-delete-row:checked")  won't work because you designated input as a class .  Try $('input:checked') for the heck of it to see if it iterates.  If that doesn't work than there are other issues.  Have you checked the console for any exisiting errors?  What browser are you using?

Comment: ok.. meant $("input.checkbox-delete-row:checked") before... anyway, first tried $("input") selector and got 13 iterations. Added a few lines without checking anything and the count didn't increase.  Changed it to $("input:checked") and got no iterations.  Something is seriously outta wack here. No JS errors in the console at all either on page load or when I click the delete button.

Comment: Maybe you should try to rewrite it using ".live()" 

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Using jquery 1.10.2 so this is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. After I wracked my brain on this for several days I finally sat down with my coworkers (fellow programmers) and I figured out what the problem was.

It was hard to demostrait in the context of SO because of the limited scope of what can be posted here.

I forgot to pass the jquery selector data into the second function call which was being called from the first. Essentially the data I needed was out of scope.

The reason I didn't think I needed to do this was because I was using jquery `on` and assumed that it would bind any subsequent events to the same event handler. I was wrong.

By setting `var checkeditems = $(".checkbox-delete-row:checked")` and then passing `checkeditems` as a param in the function call inside the first function call I got it working. But This led me to realize I have another problem.

I don't want to iterate trough the DOM to gather meta-attached HTML5 data if I need to serialized it and send it over ajax. Instead what I want to do is create hidden named inputs and use a jquery selector to find the checked ones and then `serielize()` them.

Thanks to everyone who tried I to help with this.  Sorry for all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there problem in

```
 data: {
            lineIds: 1
        }
```

Which always sends 1, not the row ids?

Comment: It's not a problem for now. That's just for testing so I don't keep getting HTTP/500 errors over and over again.  First I need to make sure it's iterating, then I can serialize the data and send it. I know how to do that and that second part shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ok, it just caught my eye ;-)
Do all checkboxes returned by Ajax have proper class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want here, but my guess is that you want to grab each selected checkbox and delete the row it's on?? If so, you'll need something like this:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class='checkbox-delete-row' name="vehicle1"/></td>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class='checkbox-delete-row' name="vehicle1"/></td>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>        
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class='checkbox-delete-row' name="vehicle1"/></td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>        
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class='checkbox-delete-row' name="vehicle1"/></td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>        
        <td>67</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<button id='button-delete-items'>button</button>
<button class='clone'>clone</button>
```

JS

```
(function(){

    $(document.body).on('click', '#button-delete-items', doDelete);
    $(document.body).on('click', '.clone', clone);

    // dynamically create checkboxes
    function clone(){
        $('.checkbox-delete-row:checked').each(function(){
            $('table').append($(this).attr('checked', false).parents('tr').clone());
        });
    }

    function doDelete(){
        $('.checkbox-delete-row:checked').each(function(idx, value){
            //idx is its index
            console.log(idx);
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        });
    }

}());
```

[JSFFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/KwA2x/)

Comment: You're basically right... but actually I need to grab an `.attr()` from each checked line and send it over AJAX. The code you've posted here doesn't work and I'm pretty sure that's because all the rows after the first row are dynamically created. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: @Phillip even if the rows are created dynamically, you should still be able to attach a `click` event onto them using `on()`.

Comment: @dcodesmoth: Haven't I already attached the event to them using .on()?  If not, what should I do differently?  What do you mean put document.ready() on the bottom? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Moving document.ready() to the bottom of the file is best practise, just to make sure that all the html has loaded before you execute any JS. Could we move this to chat, if you don't mind. So I could help you debug this. @Phillip

Comment: @Phillip try that now

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the `.each()` part. It seems to be the selector. When I change the selector to $("div") for example is iterates fine. As soon as I try to call this class as a selector, nothing.

Comment: @Phillip, I just update the fiddle code and includes implementation to dynamically create a checkbox and it works fine for me. Test it.

Comment: Yes, very good. That works but this doesn't. :( What could be wrong?

Comment: @Phillip, It's now includes a table. This is the best I got without seeing ur code in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write it differently - something like

```
$('.checkbox-delete-row').each(function(index,element){

if($(element).is(':checked') console.log(index);

})
```

But are you really really sure (tripple check it) that rows returned by AJAX have the same classes?

Are the rows properly attached to the table/table body? (I mean weirdest stuff i've ever met was based on wrong markup, that browsers tried to translate on their own)